# How to change react native app layout from api

Tags: react-native, layout, components

I have developed an store app, my boss wants a feature that from wordpress panel select predefined layout to change the whole design and choose which category to be first or .... .

I have created all designs and components that needed, but I do not know how to change app layout that I recieved from api, is there any code or help for that. This change is not about color , its about changing whole home page app layout
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that you could implement.
You'll need to create custom complete components for each layout for the homepage.
Then you'll need to call the Wordpress API to get the layout name that needs to be displayed.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import Layout1 from './components/Home/Layout1';
import Layout2 from './components/Home/Layout2';
import Layout3 from './components/Home/Layout3';
import Layout4 from './components/Home/Layout4';
import Loading from './components/Loading';

class HomePage extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      layout: null
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('https://example.com/wp-json/whatever-api-endpoint')
      .then(r => r.json());

    this.setState({
      layout: response
    });
  }

  getContentElement = () => {
    switch (this.state.layout) {
      case 'layout_1': return <Layout1 />;
      case 'layout_2': return <Layout2 />;
      case 'layout_3': return <Layout3 />;
      case 'layout_4': return <Layout4 />;
      default: return <Loading />
    }
  };

  render() {
    const contentElement = this.getContentElement();
    return (
      <View>
        {contentElement}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => HomePage);
```